# Initialize Multiple .dataTable() Individually with Separate Calls

Tags: jquery, datatables

According to the docs `.dataTable()` initialization can take care of [multiple tables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html).

But in our case, we need to initialize 3 tables separately (individually), they all have different CSS and properties.

We're finding this doesn't work:

```
$('#requestTable').dataTable( {

    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sClass": "my_class", "aTargets": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
    ]

  } );

$('#otherTable').dataTable( {

    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sClass": "my_class", "aTargets": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
    ]

  } );

$('#thirdTable').dataTable( {

    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sClass": "my_class", "aTargets": [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] }
    ]

  } );
```

Only Table1 receives the CSS Column Defs above. Table2/Table3 do not receive it, and our code is ignored.

Tables 1/2/3 have the same number of columns, and the same CSS needs to be applied

Also, if we only make one of the tables present (e.g. comment out #1 and #3), then it works. So there's something with `.dataTable()` that only does one invocation per page.

NOTE: All other attributes work with individual dataTable initialization. It's only the Class ColumnDefs that don't.

Comment: If you can share your complete code ("Some Column CSS defs"...), will be able to help you...

Comment: @Pierre I've added the code. There are 3 tables. All other indiviual settings work, it's just the CSS Target definitions that don't get applied. Also, we tried both the mixed-case property notation and the regular notation (e.g. 'targets').

Comment: If you duplicate all your class .my_class in .my_class2 and .my_class3 and apply it to the datatables 2 and 3...is the problem solved ?

Comment: And what is your datatable library version ?

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you can first try to use different classes, ie copy .my_class in .my_class2 and .my_class3
  and maybe apply it to the datatables 2 and 3
- You can also have problems with "sClass" according the datatable version your are using.